# how to create user interface to enter input dynamically in omnett++

Tags: omnet++

i want to create user interface in omnet++. For example; In my project I randomly created 1000 node in specific range (x:1500,y:1500) for simulation. But i want to enter inputs dynamically. In order to do that, I need to create interface. How can i handle this issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: i didn't try anything yet, because at the begining i need to define input size in project(static) and i finished this work. but now he wanted to me to change that as dynamically.That means, user have to enter number of node using any interfaces. Now im going to research  this topic, if you have any suggetions(other platform,program etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the OMNeT++ TkEnv (that is, the simulation GUI) is to interactively prompt its user for any parameter that has not been assigned a value.

See the @prompt ned property if you want to change the prompt.

If you do not want to use OMNET++'s facilities, of course, you can write any C++ code that would prompt your user for a value to use in the program. Your simulation is a C++ program after all.